# Bundler - could not find compatible versions for Nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, nokogiri

I am getting the following message when I execute `bundle install`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    community_engine (>= 0) ruby depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.0) ruby

    opengraph (>= 0) ruby depends on
      nokogiri (1.4.7)
```

I have tried several suggestions but nothing have worked.  Ex:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.0'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  In fact, I got even more complaints from other gems :)

Comment: Did the new set of complaints include this one? You may have to fix those to make things kosher.

Comment: Yes, the new set includes this one.

Comment: I know I had a similar issue to this in the past. I will try to figure out how I fixed it.

Comment: Try deleting your Gemfile.lock and re running 'bundle install'.

Comment: Didn't work. Community Engine wants to use ~1.5.0 and Opengraph wants 1.4.7. I don't think there is a version that will meet both these needs.

Comment: Inside your Gemfile.lock, you should be able to change the Opengraph the dependencies to be the same. But, it's a crap shoot considering each may rely on something specific to that version.